# How to identify which button clicked? (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mvvm

Continuing down the path to MVVM, I have come to button commands. After quite a bit of trial and error I finally have a working example of a `Button_Click` command using `ICommand`.

My issue is that now I have a generic event made, I can't get which button was clicked to apply some logic to it. In my example, I have not used anything where I could get the `Sender` information. Usually something like this below using `RoutedEventArgs`:

```
Button button = (Button)sender;
```

So this is what I have so far.

The `ICommand` class:

```
public class CommandHandler : ICommand
{
    private Action _action;
    private bool _canExecute;
    public CommandHandler(Action action, bool canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }
}
```

And the code to make the action:

```
private ICommand _clickCommand;
public ICommand ClickCommand => _clickCommand ?? (_clickCommand = new CommandHandler(MyAction, _canExecute));

public ViewModelBase()
{
    _canExecute = true;            
}

public void MyAction()
{
    //Apply logic here to differentiate each button
}
```

And the XAML,

```
<Button Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" Style="{StaticResource RedButtonStyle}">MyButton</Button>
```

How would I go about identifying which button is being clicked when binding the same command to other buttons?

Comment: Just curious, Why not just use *2* ICommands?

Comment: @XanderLuciano, I just thought applying some criteria diffirenitate the buttons in the method was the way to do it. Cheers

Comment: Fair enough! I just got started with MVVM about a month ago also so I understand struggle with having to adjust your thinking. Good luck!

Comment: @XanderLuciano, thanks for the support, cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *probably* shouldn't, but if you *want* to, you can use [`CommandParameter=""`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputbinding.commandparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)

You **should** just use 2 ICommands though.

XAML:

`<Button Command="{Binding ClickCommandEvent}" CommandParameter="Jack"/>`

ViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand ClickCommandEvent { get; set; }

public SomeClass()
{
    ClickCommandEvent = new RelayCommand(ClickExecute);
}

public void ClickExecute(object param)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Clicked: {param as string}");

    string name = param as string;
    if (name == "Jack")
        HighFive();
}
```

and your RelayCommand class would be [this boiler plate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030):

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for learning sake I am going to try this, but I will go with separate commands in the project. Cheers

Comment: Love the enthusiasm! Let me know if you run into any trouble! You'll love MVVM once you get a hang of it though. Have you done an `INotifyPropertyChanged` yet?

Comment: I love this stuff. Yes , I have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`, I started with `DataGrid` and all its idosyncrosis, can update, add new records etc, but still can't figure out how to delete a record with `Context.Menu`. So I am leaving that for now and started on button commands. The one I am dreading the most is `TreeView` and MVVM.

Comment: I loved how easy it was for me to pull one section out of of my Main application and make it it's own View! I didn't change a single binding, I just passed each view an instance of the same data context and it just worked! This was my result: http://i.imgur.com/UHGYi1T.gifv

Comment: That looks like a fun project!  Probably should not chat here, if you want to have a bit of a chat, lets open a private room.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the clicked `Button` :

```
<Button Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Comment: UV for taking the time to help with a helpful answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to bind all buttons to the same command. Just make a different command for each button.

Comment: OK I see, so in that respect, it is similar to your named handlers in non MVVM scenario, but this way the code is decoupled from the view. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is where WPF relies on too much code for simple actions.  I mean 30 lines of code for handling a button click is a little ridiculous but somehow we talk ourselves into it being a "good" thing because it follws a pattern.

Excessive code is excessive code. There is no reason why this should be this complicated.

Comment: it's not 30 lines of code for every button instance though ... just once in your library. How else would you handle making a button disabled due to some state of your application data? Tightly coupled spaghetti code is tightly coupled spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this is unavoidable to direct several commands to the same function to reuse the same code. I found this approach the easiest way to identify which control has been clicked. In the Xaml I set ElementName for both buttons like this:

```
      <Button Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Content="Read File"                  
              Command="{Binding ReadProButtonClick}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ReadFile}"/>          

      <Button Grid.Row="0"                  
              Grid.Column="1"
              Content="Batch Convert"                 
              Command="{Binding ReadProButtonClick}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=BatchMode}"/>
```

And then in the ViewModel, I get the name of the buttons like this:

```
 Private void ReadProButton(Object context) {           
        Controls.Button btnClicked = CType(context, System.Windows.Controls.Button)           
        processName = btnClicked.Name
        ...
 }
```

So, processName will be BatchMode or ReadFile depends on what the user clicked on.